# javascript .pop() method results in Range error

Tags: javascript

I am creating an Object für each formula. formula[0]=start_obj which are unixtimestamps and formula[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFGUD.jpg) are also unixtimestamps. in some cases i need to cut off the last stamp from the array. I tried to do so usind pop() and splice() method. both are leading into rangeError.

This is my Code:

```
    var formel_obj = {} ;
    formel_obj.start_obj = "change=[ (( x1 ))>0 ]; start=[ T(find(change)); T(1) ]; res=[start];" ;
    formel_obj.stop_obj = "change=[ (( x1 ))<0 ]; stop=[ T(find(change)); T(1) ]; res=[stop];" ;

var label, formel ;

for(label in formel_obj) {
    formel = formel_obj[label] ;
    this[label] = new Array() ;
    this[label] = wedge.calc.eval_with_timeaxis( formel, tag_x1, {timebase: interval_length, intervals: [ { start: t_axis_start, end: t_axis_stop } ] })[0] ;   // creating for both formel ojects an array from function - see console log
}

last=start_obj[Object.keys(start_obj).length - 1] ;
pre_last=start_obj[Object.keys(start_obj).length - 2] ;

if (last < pre_last) {
    console.log(start_obj.length) ;
    console.log(start_obj) ;
    start_obj.pop() ;       results in Range error , why?
}
```

the array(s) from console look like:

```
>> start_obj
[1446153600, 1446163200, 1446170400, 1446229200, 1446270600, 1446364200, 1446366600, 1446415200, 1446422400, 1446436200, 1446452400, 1446457200, 1446472200, 1446133800]
>> stop_obj
[1446157800, 1446164400, 1446173400, 1446267000, 1446363000, 1446364800, 1446409200, 1446421800, 1446435000, 1446450600, 1446456600, 1446464400, 1446472800, 1446133800]
>> start_obj[0]
1446153600
>> start_obj.length
14
>> start_obj.pop()
is RangeError .....
```

i really have no idea why ;(

any thoughts?

.

**EDIT_1:**

its an Runtime array, see the screen from console.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFGUD.jpg)

**EDIT_2:**

Thanks again guys, your awsome. i figured out thats definitly not an regular array. i wrote a function which converts this messy array (or what ever this is) into an regular one. This is commercial software and i dont have direct access to these "background functions" what wedge.what.ever() is doing.
Anyway thank you all guys for lightning fast discussion taking place here.

here is the transformfunction:

```
function form_reg_array (runtimearray) {
    var item ;
    newarray = new Array() ;
    for (item in runtimearray) {
        newarray.push(runtimearray[item]) ;
    }
    return newarray
}
```

i call it like:

```
start_obj=form_reg_array(start_obj)
```

which transform it into regular array! Thanks for loud thinking everyone.

Comment: Where is your start_obj variable defined? Does it exist on the formel_obj object? You may be trying to pop from an uninitialized array.

Comment: What kind of data does `wedge.calc.eval_with_timeaxis( ... )[0]` return? You create an array, but then you replace it with that value. If that's not actually an array, you can't use it as an array.

Comment: @CameronTinker: The `start_obj` variable is created in the loop: `this[label] = ...` where `label == "start_obj"`.

Comment: @Guffa haha Yes, I see that now. :)

Comment: thanks for those quick replys :). Wedge is an special process analyses software. See my edit above

Comment: @derdigge Drill down into the prototype of that object (and keep drilling until you reach `Object`) to see if it at any point supports the `pop()` method. It might also be useful if you could enlighten us on what library you are using here.

Comment: I would say it is Wedge. The image dies not help. we need to see the pop method that is being called.

Comment: Re second edit. Yes you do have access to the back ground functions, this is javascript. If its obstiocated copy it into a code editor and apply a code formater to it. Plus??? `newarray.push=runtimearray[item] ;`  is this a typo?

Comment: Yes Sir is this a typo!

Answer (score 2):

When I run the following code (simplified from your example), it works:

```js
var start = [1446153600, 1446163200, 1446170400, 1446229200, 1446270600, 1446364200, 1446366600, 1446415200, 1446422400, 1446436200, 1446452400, 1446457200, 1446472200, 1446133800]
var end = [1446157800, 1446164400, 1446173400, 1446267000, 1446363000, 1446364800, 1446409200, 1446421800, 1446435000, 1446450600, 1446456600, 1446464400, 1446472800, 1446133800]

var element = document.createElement('p');
element.textContent = end.pop();
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

So the error is probably the fact that in your example code, I can only see `formel_obj.start_obj` being declared, not the actual `start_obj`, which would mea that undefined cannot `pop`. To help you better, we need to know whether you are running inside a `this` context or not. If not, better declare using `window`, or, well, not like that at all. If you are using `this` to declare it, you *also* need `this` to read it. So maybe use `this.start_obj` will work.

Comment: Ow cool, I have been using document.write with safari as an empty fiddle with a console log always look so... Unfinished. Good to know!

Comment: (oops, I accidentally deleted my comment, read it before ^) document.write may not work in sandboxed environments such as a fiddle.

Comment: The `start_obj` and `stop_obj` variables are created in the loop.

Comment: @Guffa that is only true if this is running inside a `this`-able context, as well as the fact that - even though _declared_ as `this.something` - it is being _requested_ as a regular `something`, which does not have a connection to the environment.

Comment: @somethinghere: Obviously it's running in the global context, as the variables are actually created. It has been verified that the variables do exist and are accessible, that's not the problem.

Comment: @Guffa thank you for verifying that, but the issue is obviously _not_ `pop()` - thats the main reason for this answer. If anything, the next statement is suspicious for delivering _something_ but we dont know what: `this[label] = wedge.calc.eval_with_timeaxis( formel, tag_x1, {timebase: interval_length, intervals: [ { start: t_axis_start, end: t_axis_stop } ] })[0] `

Comment: @somethinghere: Yes, that's why I asked in the comments to the question what that does return.

Answer (score 2):

The ES6 document shows that pop does not generate the Range error. [ECMA Array.pop](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.pop)

The pop you are calling is not the native Array pop. You will have to supply the code for that function for us to help. Also as it is not native you should be able to step into it with a debugger and find the source of the problem.

Comment: It comes down to this line, right: `this[label] = wedge.calc.eval_with_timeaxis( formel, tag_x1, {timebase: interval_length, intervals: [ { start: t_axis_start, end: t_axis_stop } ] })[0]`  - this line is setting it to _something_ that is _not_ necessarily a regular array.

Comment: @SomeThingHere Your guess is as good as mine. It looks messy is all I know, what it does is anyone's guess, what this is referencing is also a unknown with what we have.

Answer (score 0):

The `RuntimeArray` type obviously doesn't support all methods of an array, or does it incorrectly.

As it does have the `length` property and the numbered properties, you can do the dirty work yourself to remove the last item:

```
start_obj.length--;
delete start_obj[start_obj.length];
```

This code would also work for an actual array. Decreasing the length will also remove the last item, and the `delete` will have no work to do.